# parse/turn an unsorted list of links into an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, html-parsing

I have an unsorted html list in form of of a string like this:

```
<ul class="localizations">
  <li>
    <a href="/project/en-EN/test-page">English</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/project/de-DE/german-test-page">German</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/project/fr-FR/french-test-page-version">French</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(note that the `href` attribute can be completely arbitrary)

Now I am looking for a way in my View to parse this string in a way that will result in an array that has the link text as index, and the link's `href` attribute as value, so I can later use `<a href="@localizations['de-DE']">...</a>` to get the german link, etc.

I'm also thinking about using this to generate [rel="alternate" hreflang="x"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) links in the `<head>` so I can't use JS at runtime but have to do this in c#/razor in the masterpage when the page is created.

I am rather new to asp.net/c#/mvc, could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: An array that has the linktext as **index** and href attribute as value?? Are you sure that you mean array and not dictionary? Apart from that, use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.

Comment: On second thought I don't need the link text in the array, just the hrf urls would be enough. HtmlAgilityPack is not installed and I do not have the ability to add it (or other extensions, plugins, etc.)

Comment: you don't need to install it, it's just a small dll.